# Zend Framework 2 remove hard coded path from unit test

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2

I'm just going through the Zend Framework 2 unit test tutorial. During the process of setting up the unit test they insert a hard coded path to the application config in the `setUp` method:

```
namespace AlbumTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class AlbumControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include '/var/www/zf2-tutorial/config/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }
}
```

I can't believe this is actually done and used as an example.

The question is, how do you get the Application config in a unit test `setUp` method without hard coding it's path?

**UPDATE:**

Another related question I have regarding this is, why does the unit test for a "module" need access to the application configuration? Isn't the "unit test" for a module supposed to be isolated to this single module?

**UPDATE 2:**

After fiddling about for a while I found out a related issue. During the tutorial where the Album module is created it is pointed out to rather than returning the config structure in the `Module.php` for the `getAutoloaderConfig` method, to use Composer to create the class map. However, when you do this, your unit tests will not work since you're missing part of the configuration. To solve this part of the problem you need to create a `autoload_classmap.php` in your module base directory and return an empty array in it. Then use the code as outlined in the `getAutoloaderConfig` for your tests to work.

I still haven't found a solution to the hard coded application config problem and as to why is actually needs access to it in the first place. I'm testing a module, not an application.

Comment: I would like to know the Zend official answer about this. I also don't understand why one would like to have all modules boostrapped when unit testing one of them. From my point of view, it defeats the purpose of module unit testing !

Answer (score 1):

I always use the function presented below, directly from http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/tutorials/unittesting.html

```
protected static function findParentPath($path)
{
    $dir = __DIR__;
    $previousDir = '.';
    while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
        $dir = dirname($dir);
        if ($previousDir === $dir) {
            return false;
        }
        $previousDir = $dir;
    }
    return $dir . '/' . $path;
}
```

Place that function in your ControllerTest class, and use it in the `setUp` function, like so:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $modulePath = static::findParentPath("module");
    $this->setApplicationConfig(
        include $modulePath . '/../config/application.config.php'
    );
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sitting hard codding for application configuration path into `$this->setApplicationConfig()` method Like [Zend 2 Official Doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#your-first-controller-test) is **very very Bad Code**.

To Solve this problem, you can use answer of [@slawoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3079926/slawoj) who use `findParentPath($path)` method from [Bootstrap class into same Zend 2 Official Doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#bootstrapping-your-tests) to get application configuration path.

There another answer, may be better:

Use Same [Bootstrap class into Zend 2 Official Doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#bootstrapping-your-tests) and add a static member save application configuration array when to use it to initiate service manager static member.

**Bootstrap.php**

```
class Bootstrap
{
    /**
     * ServiceManger Static member
     * @var ServiceManager
     */
    private static $serviceManager;

    /**
     * Application Configuration static member
     * @var array
     */
    private static $applicationConfiguration;

    /**
     * Initialize Tests Bootstrap
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        static::initAutoloader();
        if (file_exists(static::findParentPath('code') . '/config/application.config.php')) {
            // include application configuration
            $configuration = require static::findParentPath('code') . '/config/application.config.php';
            // initialize application configuration static member
            static::$applicationConfiguration = $configuration;
            // initialize service manager static member
            $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
            $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $configuration);
            $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
            static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Application Service Manager
     * @return ServiceManager
     */
    public static function getServiceManager()
    {
        return static::$serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get Application Configuration
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getApplicationConfig()
    {
        return static::$applicationConfiguration;
    }

    /**
     * Get Full Path include given path with it's parent path
     * @param string $path path name which we want to get it's parent
     * @return string
     */
    public static function findParentPath($path)
    {
        $dir = __DIR__;
        $previousDir = ".";
        // loop on Directories Path until get parent path
        while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
            if ($previousDir == $dir) {
                return false;
            }
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }

   // ........
}
```

Then Use application configuration static member to `$this->setApplicationConfig()` method.

**Your AlbumControllerTest class**

```
class AlbumControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            Bootstrap::getApplicationConfig()
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }
}
```

may the last explanation solve your first question

> how do you get the Application config in a unit test setUp method
>   without hard coding it's path?

**In Other hands**: for your second question

> why is actually needs access to it in the first place. I'm testing a
>   module, not an application

As it recommended to most of Test case Classes extends `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase` Like [They said into Zend 2 official Doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#your-first-controller-test)

> The `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase` class we extend here helps us
>   setting up the application itself, helps with dispatching and other
>   tasks that happen during a request, as well offers methods for
>   asserting request params, response headers, redirects and more

So your Test case classes may use `getApplicationServiceLocator()` to get `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager` instance OR use `getRequest()` to get `Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface` instance for http Request OR `getResponse()` to `Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface` for Http Response, all This methods use internally `getApplication()` method Which initiate `Zend\Mvc\ApplicationInterface` Object Using your the Application config Then you need to use `$this->setApplicationConfig()` method into `setUp()` method of your test case classes to Set your the Application config.

All methods I had give Them as Example, allocated into [`AbstractControllerTestCase`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/blob/master/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php) Which [`AbstractHttpControllerTestCase`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/blob/master/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractHttpControllerTestCase.php) class Extends it.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
include  dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))))).'/config/application.config.php'
```

Comment: What if my module and it's tests end up in the vendor directory as a module?

Comment: @Luke If you're using the default ZF2 app layout, module/ lies directly besides vendor/.

Comment: What about modules that sit inside the vendor directory? As in, 3rd party modules?